# conda, "Solving environment: failed" error on Linux CentOS 7

Tags: python, anaconda, environment, conda, miniconda

I installed Conda through [Miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) on my laptop running Linux CentOS 7.

If I run the command `conda update conda`, I get the following error:

```
conda update conda
Solving environment: failed

NotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to a required path.
  path: /path/to/custom/dir/pkgs/urls.txt
  uid: 1000
  gid: 1000

If you feel that permissions on this path are set incorrectly, you can manually
change them by executing

  $ sudo chown 1000:1000 /path/to/custom/dir/pkgs/urls.txt

In general, it's not advisable to use 'sudo conda'.
```

I've no idea on how to solve this issue; I also asked on the [Bioconda GitHub page](https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes/issues/7950) but nobody replied.

Any suggestion on how to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Where did you install Miniconda? i.e., in what directory?

Comment: `/home/davide/miniconda2/`

Answer (score 1):

This is discussed in conda issue #7267  (https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7267).

You may have logged in using sudo, perhaps as `sudo -u davide bash`?

If so, then the following command will show SUDO_COMMAND as the command used to become the user, as well as SUDO_USER, SUDO_UID and SUDO_GID:

```
$ set | grep SUDO
```

You can instead use `sudo su - davide` to get a clean context with no SUDO definitions.

I encountered the same issue when administering a shared conda environment via ansible.  My solution was to use the following to operate as the conda package owner:

```
- name: update conda environment
  command: conda update -y --all
  become: yes
  become_user: conda
  become_method: su
```

Whether or not it is a good idea to share an anaconda installation on a cluster is a separate question.

Comment: Thanks @Neapolitan, but it did not work :-/ Nothing changed